# Animate menu bar on scrolling window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say, I have a navigation `div` like this:

```
  #navigation {
      position:fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: #FFF;
      z-index:999;
      padding-top: 25px;
      padding-left: 45px;
  }
```

If the user scrolls I want to behave it like it would be `position:absolute`, so that it disappears in the top of the browser window. But after a short delay I want it to slide from the top back in to its old position. How can I realize this with JS?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isInAction = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!isInAction){
        isInAction = true;
        $( "#navigation" ).animate({
            top: "-" + $("#navigation").innerHeight() + "px"
        }).delay(1000).animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 800, function() {
            isInAction = false;
        });;
    }
});
```

You can change `.delay(1000)` to change the delay time.

The isInAction var is defined to prevent repeating animation when you scroll constantly.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gvjeyywa/3/)**

**Update:**

If you want to restrict this action only on scroll down, So modify code like this:

```
var isInAction = false;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       if (!isInAction){
           isInAction = true;
           $( "#navigation" ).animate({
               top: "-" + $("#navigation").innerHeight() + "px"
           }).delay(1000).animate({
               top: "0px"
           }, 800, function() {
               isInAction = false;
           });
       }
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gvjeyywa/4/)**

Comment: …This is basically it … But instead of a fade out, cal i let the DIV move? I want to let it "fall" or "slide down" to the position declared in the CSS

Comment: … YEAH! Thank you so much, this it what I wanted! And how can I let this only happen while the user scrolls to the bottom and not while he is scrolling back to top?

Comment: YEEES! This was really helpful! Thank you a lot! And answered so fast!

Comment: … still a little question… Where do I set a speed for letting the div sliding up? These lines here are for sliding down, right?

    800, function() {
               isInAction = false;
           });
       }

Comment: `800` in `}, 800, function() {` section is the animation speed and `1000` in `.delay(1000)` section is the delay time.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i mean i want to behave it while slinding down like it would be postion:absolute, so i slides away in the same speed like all the other content on the site… And the let it became postion:fixed; top:0 … Is that possilbe?

Comment: Is it understandable what I want?

Comment: Heres my new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591872/reposition-div-after-scrolling

Comment: can the action be halted until the first up-scroll? The nav stays gone until the user scrolls up, no sliding back down at all until the user scrolls up

Answer (score 0):

If you use position:absolute to position the element then you can use:

```
var windowTop = $('body').scrollTop;
```

Will give you the offset from the top of the page that the window is currently displaying.

```
$('#element').css('top', windowTop + 'px');
```

Will set the element to that position

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/1w819L3x/) to see a working example. the code is the one below:
**HTML**:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='navigation'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper{
    height: 600px;
}
#navigation {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index:999;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  }
```

**jQuery/javascript**:

```
$('#wrapper').bind('mousewheel',function(e){
    if ($('#navigation').is(':animated')){
        return false;
    }
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        $('#navigation').animate({
            top:'-' + $('#navigation').innerHeight(),
        }).delay(1200).animate({
            top: '0px',
        });
    }
});
```

The wheelDelta property returns an integer value indicating the distance that the mouse wheel rolled. A negative value means the mouse wheel rolled down.

Hope it useful!

Comment: …it bounces! It does not stop getting up and down! Somehow :-) … Let us please change the position:fixed to absolute …
Basically i just want this: I have a div at top:0px with position:absolute… The users scrolls, so it disappears. But after a short delay it slides from top to stick at top:0px… If the users scrolls down further / again, same effect…